# How to launch Edge with Open package on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, windows, npm, electron, microsoft-edge

I am using the [Open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) package to launch URLs cross-browser. There doesn't seem to be great documentation on how to launch with specific browsers on each OS.

I've found that you can do this for Mac

```
const open = require('open');

await open('https://www.github.com', { app: 'microsoft edge' });
```

Meaning that the keyword for Mac is `microsoft edge`.

I'm trying to figure out the keyword for Windows. I've tried `microsoft edge`

I've also tried `microsoft-edge`

```
await open('https://www.github.com', { app: 'microsoft-edge' });
```

and `edge`

```
await open('https://www.github.com', { app: 'edge' });
```

But none of those seem to work.

Does anyone know the keyword for Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Deepak-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10309381/deepak-msft) for pointing me in the right direction. The keyword has to be the name of the .exe file. In my case the name was `msedge`, so this is the code that worked for me on Windows 10

```
await open('https://www.github.com', { app: 'msedge' });
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Windows platform, I found that it needs to be exe file name of the app that you want to launch.

[Examples for opening with different browsers on different platforms #177](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open/issues/177)

Another information I found in the docs that for Windows it uses the **Start** command. So you can also try to test with it.

[image]

[API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open#api)